# What do references like "Docc Rom." and similar mean?

Tags: meaning, history, abbreviations

In the book [*Giordano Bruno: His Life and Thought*, by Dorothea Waley Singer](http://www.positiveatheism.org/hist/bruno07f.htm),  references often have a form of

> 18 Doc. Ven. XV.

or

> 49 Docc. Rom. XX, XXI.

How to decipher them?

Comment: Unless you already know what documents these notes refer to, it's anybody's guess. Doc will be Documentum, Docc Documenta. Ven. could be Venetianum/-a, Rom. Romanum/-a. The Arabic numerals could be page numbers, the Roman numerals document numbers. But there is really no way to tell: the author ought to *at least* give you the full name of the documents in the first note in which he refers to them: perhaps you could search for the first reference to these documents in the book. Or in the bibliography/appendix.

Comment: The OP is looking at the book online, and the bibliography is not online. My advice would be to check the print edition.

Comment: @Cerberus The prefix numerals are likely to identify a volume.

Comment: Can you infer this from a given link? Any one case please, not namely that I mentioned. I found no resolution you told. Sorry I am not fluent English.

Comment: I am afraid that these cannot be reliably decoded without access to the complete Bibliography. There are a few general tendencies we can comment on, like a doubling of the last letter of an abbreviation making something plural, but without access to the full work, you cannot know what they are abbreviating.  The bibliography is not online. Also, there are numerous encoding errors in the transcription, causing spurious question marks all over the place.

Comment: @MEd: I have no idea, could be anything; but why do you think so?

Comment: I see the folks at History.SE weren't much help either. I'd suggest 1)look in other books on the subject, particularly those published before 1950 2)look for a Renaissance History forum with reasonably high-powered academics. But these references may be peculiar to Singer.

Comment: @Cerberus  The author does *not* give a full first reference, unless  "Doc. Rom. I [Spampanato, Documenti della vita di Giordano Bruno, p. 154]" identifies *Docc.Rom.* But the [footnotes](http://www.positiveatheism.org/hist/bruno01f.htm) to Ch. 1 are confusing. See especially n.1

Comment: Hello Suzan and welcome. Reading your question I infer, with some degree of  sureness, that you might be interested to follow our new proposal [Italian Language & Usage](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42949/italian-language-usage). I like Giordano Bruno, and I was happy to ear that someone in the world is studying his opera. Congratulations. However, FWIW, I agree with MetaEd: there is no way to correctly answer to your question without consulting the print edition. Furthermore, apart this problem, I think the question, albeit interesting (+1), is too localized as per the FAQs.

Comment: @Carlo_R.  I'm afraid you're right. Any question we won't answer is Too Localized -- unless it's Too Generalized, to the point of asking The Meaning of Life.

Comment: Compare *71 Doc. Rom. XXIV.* and *49 Docc. Rom. XX, XXI.* In the first, there is one *documentum (XXIV)* and the second, there are two *documenta (XX,XXI).*

Comment: Sorry @StoneyB, but, although I do not have answers to questions on English language, I have a precise one on the meaning of life.

Comment: @StoneyB: Exactly, and the author *should* have provided the full title in the first note. As to *[Spampanato, Documenti della vita di Giordano Bruno, p. 154]*, that looks like the book from which the author copied the reference, which book presumably interprets the original text as found in "Doc. Rom. I". Or Spampanato could have published an edition of the original source.

Comment: @Peter I'm unsure if these abbreviations are related with Italian language, but I confirm your observation. In my language we twice the final letter of  abbreviations when the related words are in plural form.

Comment: @Cerberus I have just seen that you have already noticed the difference between Doc. and Docc.

Comment: @Carlo_R.  Yes, but if it's not My answer then it's Not Constructive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In 1933, Vicenzo Spampanato published many documents on the life of Bruno under the title *Documenti della vita di Giordano Bruno*.

He divided these documents into the *Documenti Veneti* and the *Documenti Romani*, and numbered each document with a Roman numeral. *Docc* stands for the plural *Documenti*.

So *Docc. Rom. XX, XXI.* means documents XX and XXI from the Documenti Romani.

> Vincenzo  Spampanato, *Documenti  della  vita  di  Giordano Bruno*, Opuscoli Filosofici IV (Florence 1933)

Comment: Perfect! Isn't this a historical question, eh? :)

Comment: P.S. 49 and 18 are just Singer's footnote numbers.

Comment: For what it's worth, here's the earlier, 1921, edition, which has fewer documents. [**Vol I**](http://archive.org/stream/vitadigiordanobr01spam#page/n5/mode/2up), [**Vol II**](http://archive.org/stream/vitadigiordanobr02spam#page/n3/mode/2up). *Documenti* start on page 599, in Vol II, and there are a bunch more sections than just Roman and Venetian. What goes before that is the *Life* itself. But Cerberus nailed it.

Comment: @StoneyB Pardon, may I ask you if with the verb 'nail' you mean 'To accomplish (a task) completely and successfully'?

Comment: @SuzanCioc: Ah OK! This is historical, yes.

Comment: @Carlo_R. Rem acu tetigisti!

Comment: @tchrist: You mean actute tetigisti?

Comment: @Cerberus Without apocopation, yes.

Comment: @Carlo_R.  Ayup. To the wall. (retreating into the vernacular)

Comment: Thank you @StoneyB. I have learn both a new word and a new idiom. It is interesting to notice the nuance between 'nail', 'to the wall' and 'rem acum tetigisti'.

Comment: @Carlo_R.  Another good one, equally applicable, is "nothing but net".

Comment: @tchrist: You're saying it as if it were a normal thing to do...